# iPhone HTML Select Box displaying "x items" as the select box default text

Tags: html, css, iphone, mobile, safari

I am trying to include a multiple select box in my HTML that also appears on our mobile site. I am running into an issue where the select box simply just says "5 items". I want it to say "select data to plot". If I click on the select, all of the correct information is there. Do you know what could cause this? Here is the HTML:

```html
<select id=selPts1 name=selPts1 size=10 multiple class='selParams'>
    <option value='A_LVL' selected>A_LVL</option>
    <option value='B_LVL' selected>B_LVL</option>
    <option value='C_LVL' selected>C_LVL</option>
    <option value='D_LVL' selected>D_LVL</option>
    <option value='E_LVL' selected>E_LVL</option>
</select>
```

What can I do to make the default text just have something like a title?

Edit: [image: Select box says “x items”]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want correctly, you just need to add one more option and it doesn't need to have a value.

```html
    <select id=selPts1 name=selPts1 size=10 multiple class='selParams'>
      <option selected>Select data to plot</option>
      <option value='A_LVL'>A_LVL</option>
      <option value='B_LVL'>B_LVL</option>
      <option value='C_LVL'>C_LVL</option>
      <option value='D_LVL'>D_LVL</option>
      <option value='E_LVL'>E_LVL</option>
    </select>
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I believe it was saying 5 items because all your options had 'selected' in them. So I removed them and only have it present in the option you wished to have as a title.

Comment: I made the adjustment but I am now seeing the picture that I inserted in the “edit” section of my post. Do you know why this isn’t working?

Comment: @Dplusa25 I don't know what your code looks like so it's hard to know what is happening exactly.

Comment: I also don't know what is happening vs what you're expecting should be happening.

Comment: The html that is causing the odd label is in my post. I want the area that says “5 items” or “0 items” to instead say “please select variables to plot”

Comment: It should, until selections are made. It works as expected on my iPhone.

Comment: That’s the thing, when nothing is selected, it still just says “0 items”

Comment: You're keeping the option you want as your title selected?

Comment: I changed the html to look like what you answered as.

Comment: Strange...maybe a script is interfering?

Comment: I feel like safari browser has a css overwrite. When I emulate in chrome an iphone7, it doesn’t behave like the picture I linked. But testing on actual iPhone it has the strange behavior.